# compare two lists containing objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, class, compare

I created a object in Powershell which looks like this:

```
Class groupObject{ 
    [string] $Name
    [string] $Domain

    groupObject([string] $inputName, [string] $inputDomain){
        $this.Name = $inputName
        $this.Domain = $inputDomain
    }

    setName([string] $inputName){ 
        $this.Name = $inputName 
    }

    setDomain([string] $inputDomain){ 
        $this.Domain = $inputDomain 
    } 

    [string] getName(){ 
        return $this.Name
    }

    [string] getDomain(){ 
        return $this.Domain
    }

    # Compare two groupObjects.
    [boolean] isEqual([groupObject] $ADgroup){
        return ($ADgroup.getName() -eq $this.getName() -and $ADgroup.getDomai() -eq $this.getDomain())
    }    
}
```

And I've got two ArrayLists containing `groupObject`s from different sources.

Now I want to compare those two lists and find all groups which are only in one of them. I am trying to use something like this `$onlyList2= $List2 | ?{$List1 -notcontains $_}`. But I'm not sure how I can do this using my `groupObject`s. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the `Compare-Object` cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, Compare-Object is the answer: with your PowerShell code, you can add:

```
$ListLeft = @(
    [groupObject]::new('NameLeft1', 'DomainLeft')
    [groupObject]::new('NameBoth1', 'DomainBoth')
)

$ListRight = @(
    [groupObject]::new('NameRight1', 'DomainRight')
    [groupObject]::new('NameBoth1', 'DomainBoth')
)


'Records which are unique in $ListLeft, comparing Name and Domain:'
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ListLeft -DifferenceObject $ListRight -Property 'Name','Domain' | Where-Object SideIndicator -EQ '<=' | FT

'Records which are unique in $ListRight, comparing Name and Domain:'
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ListLeft -DifferenceObject $ListRight -Property 'Name', 'Domain' | Where-Object SideIndicator -EQ '=>' | FT
```

This will be the result:

```
Records which are unique in $ListLeft, comparing Name and Domain:

Name      Domain     SideIndicator
----      ------     -------------
NameLeft1 DomainLeft <=

Records which are unique in $ListRight, comparing Name and Domain:

Name       Domain      SideIndicator
----       ------      -------------
NameRight1 DomainRight =>
```